# Outlook email issue

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, winmail.dat

I have a weird issue where I send an email to someone and, when I receive their reply email, the contents of their reply does not show in Outlook 2019 (desktop app). There is a message body but it is simply my email to them (i.e. the email thread minus their reply).

What is strange is that I can see their reply when I view the same email on webmail and on the Android Outlook app. Furthermore, the content of their reply is contained in the "Content preview" in the email headers.

On the Android Outlook app, when I view their reply email it only shows their reply with a winmail.dat attachment. Upon opening the winmail.dat attachment (with a winmail.dat attachment viewer), I can see an RTF file with the email thread minus their reply and this is appears to replace their reply when I try to view their reply email in the Outlook desktop app.

I've had this with two senders who both appear to use Apple devices. Would appreciate any insights as to how to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

It's so obvious the issue is caused by senders.
For further investigation, they should be involved to provide some information about their Email client software or web applications.

It seems their clients treat the accepted Emails with a special method because of some unknown reasons, which I also have no idea on. Are these weird Emails encrypted by some security web app since their content is confidential?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).